# Calculating percentages when values are weighted

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset whereby all individuals >10cm are measured and a sample is taken of the individuals <10cm. I then calculate a raising factor for the sample of individuals <10cm based on weights (weights are recorded).

I can then plot a length frequency graph in ggplot by assigning the raising factor as weight in ggplot. However, now I would like to calculate the percentage of the dataset <10cm and the percentage >10cm, and I need to use the raising factor to account for the sampling system. In the data set below, each value of 6 counts as two entries of 6, each value of 3 counts as six values of 3, etc. for the length frequency graph.

```
Length     Raising factor
6          2
19         1
3          6
11         1 
14         1
8          5
```

Is there a suggestion for how to calculate the percentage of lengths <10cm based on the raising factor?

Comment: Thanks for providing sample data, but can you add your expected output as well?

Comment: The result would be 81.25% of the lengths are less than 10cm. Because of the raising factor, the data set would be as follows: 6, 6, 19, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 11, 14, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8. Therefore 13 values <10cm and 3 values >10cm.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it :

```
with(df1, sum(Raising_factor[Length < 10] / sum(Raising_factor)))
# [1] 0.8125
```

We filter the weighted occurences for which the length is eligible and compute their proportion relative to all weighted occurences.

**data**

```
df1 <- read.table(h=T,text="
Length     Raising_factor
6          2
19         1
3          6
11         1 
14         1
8          5")
```